# How do I add a PIXI container into a Phaser Game?

Tags: javascript, html5, phaser

How do I add a PIXI container into a Phaser Game?

I have a game made ONLY with PIXI. but now i would like to port it to a Phaser.

All my game content happens inside a pixi container "screenContainer".  I tried to add a pixi container like this.

```
var created = function() {
       screenContainer = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer();
       var sprite = m.game.add.existing(screenContainer);
}

var.game = new Phaser.Game(gameWidth, gameHeight, Phaser.AUTO, "divId", { create: created });
```

but it stops here

```
"phaser.js" line 33067 
/**
* The core update - as called by World.
* @method Phaser.Group#update
* @protected
*/
Phaser.Group.prototype.update = function () {
var i = this.children.length;

while (i--)
{
    this.children[i].update(); // UPDATE IS UNDEFINED
}

};
```

because Pixi.Container, does not have "update" method.

Is there any other way to add a pixi container inside a phaser game?

Answer (score 1):

All Phaser display objects (group, sprites...) are based on PIXI ones.
PIXI objects can be rendered in phaser render tree. the only problem is the update and postUpdate function.

I solved it adding this simple patch:

```
PIXI.DisplayObject.prototype.update = function () { };
PIXI.DisplayObject.prototype.postUpdate = function () { };
```

this patch adds a empty function for "update" and "postUpdate" methods in PIXI displayObjects prototype. In that case Phaser update tree founds a function to execute.